# Adding custom UI to change password screen

Tags: c#, credentials, credential-providers

Hello I would like to add a custom text ui in the top left hand corner of the change a password screen in order to provide my organizations password requirements. I am not really looking to modify how the credential provider is performing the authentication call I just would like to add the ui. We are currently using a third party app but the way the app is handling it is causing issues with other applications that we are using and so we are looking into replacing it. I have been trying to read up on Microsoft docs and articles on this but all the documents I found just spoke and gave guidance on how to create a whole new authentication process which like I said I do not necessarily want to do.

Comment: See following : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-security/admin/recovering-and-changing-passwords-cs

Comment: That link is for web applications. I am looking to add ui to the windows change a password screen.

Comment: Use the following in the link : MembershipUser usr = Membership.GetUser(username);
string resetPwd = usr.ResetPassword();
usr.ChangePassword(resetPwd, newPassword);